# 'ReferenceError: require is not defined' while importing fs module

Tags: node.js, require

I am new to NodeJS. I was importing the 'fs' module in NodeJS and this happened.

[image]

Is this because of the new import syntax in the current versions?
What went wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because something is telling nodejs that this is the newer ESM module.  This could be your package.json file or something else.  In an ESM module file, you use `import`, not `require()` to load modules.

You can see in the stack trace where it shows `Object.loadESM` and that's how you know it is trying to load this module as an ESM module.

With an ESM module, perhaps you want this:

```
import fs from "fs";
```

or

```
import * as fs from'fs';
```

Or, if you intend to use a CommonJS module instead (where you can use `require()`), then we need to see your package.json file to figure out why the loader is attempting to load your file as an ESM module.

Comment: You are right. I am leaving the package.json as it is and using the 'import' syntax. Better to learn the new syntax.